# How to let program to be killed after root filesystem cleanly unmounted?

Tags: linux, debian, shutdown, init

I'm using qemu-nbd and ntfs-3g (please don't ask why) on Debian stretch to mount my root filesystem. But on shutdown, these programs get killed first, which causes my root filesystem not unmounted cleanly and init script unable to be stopped successfully. How can these programs get killed after my root filesystem unmounted cleanly? nbd and nfs root filesystem can be unmounted safely, so this should not be an exception right?

Comment: With systemd (that's the default if you installed stretch), sysvinit (that's the default if you upgraded from jessie), or some other init system?

Comment: @Gilles sysvinit